# $p$-subgroup of $G$ with $p$ a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> If $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ then $[N_G(H) : H] ≡ [G:H]\operatorname{mod} p$.

**Proof:**

Let S be the set of left cosets of H in G. H acts on S by left translation, 
$h · aH = haH$, then $|S| = [G : H]$.
So $xH∈S_0 ⇐⇒ hxH=xH ∀h∈H ⇐⇒ x^{−1}hxH=H ∀h∈H ⇐⇒ x^{−1}Hx=H ⇐⇒ x∈ N_G(H)$
$|S_0| = [N_G(H) : H]$
By the fact that $ |H|=p^n$ and H acts on S we have $|S|≡|S_0|$ mod p.
So $[G:H]≡[N_G(H):H]$ modp.

Is it correct my proof?.

> And If p divides $[G : H]$ then $N_G(H)  ≠ H $

**Proof:**

$0≡[G:H]≡[N_G(H):H]≥1$.
So $[N_G(H) : H] ≥ 1$, thus $ N_G(H) ≠ H$ .

Is it correct?

Please help!!! T_T

Comment: what's $NG(\cdot)$?

Comment: He means $N_G$.

Comment: Yeap $N_G(H)$ IS it correct the proof?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct. In the second half, you want to add that $p\mid [N_G(H):H]$ and $[N_G(H):H] \geq 1$ and hence $[N_G(H):H] \geq p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Prove the following:

If a finite $\;p-$group $\;G\;$ acts on a finite set $\;X\;,\;\;$ and if we denote $\,X^G:=\{x\in X\;;\;g\cdot x=x\;,\;\forall\,g\in G\}\;$ (the set of fixed points) , then

$$|X^G|=|X|\pmod p$$

Now, for your case: define an action $\;H\times X\to X\;,\;\;h\cdot(xH):=(hx)H\;$ , where $\;X\;$ is the set of left cosets of $\;H \;$ in $\;G\;$, then $\;N_G(H)=X^H\;$ . Now apply the first part...